# RTS threshold set to 0

Tags: ad-hoc-wireless

I know what if you lower RTS threshold value too much, you can introduce more latency into the network, as Requests to Send are increased so much that the shared medium is reserved more often than necessary but what can I expect at 0 value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited) Sorry. I meant the following:

If you set the RTS value to 0 then the behavior is implementation based. Some vendors might have a "disable RTS" concept, and other might have "always enable RTS" concept. If you want to surely disable RTS, then set a very high value like 2500 or 3000. But I would recommend you do the following to set the right RTS threshold value:

1. Packet Size: If the packet size is large, then it makes sense since you would want to reserve the medium. Run a traffic profile test on your network to determine most of the packet sizes.
2. Network density: If you have or if you anticipate large number of clients on the network per Wi-Fi router (Access Point), then you can enable RTS/CTS mechanism to take care of hidden station issues.

Comment: i dont understand how this answers my question ..

Comment: Sorry I edited my answer.

Comment: so "always enable RTS"  at RTS=0 means what? After every 0 bites RTS/CTS is needed ? So there cant be any communication?

Comment: So, for RTS threshold = 0 you might have 2 types of settings:
1. Disable RTS
2. Send RTS for every packet
The implementation is vendor dependent.
To make sure you **disable** RTS, set the value to > 3000.